# split log of a multi-threaded application

Tags: regex, perl, unix, split

I have a multi-threaded application which generates logs as mentioned:

```
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:23 2013  <no machine>  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta_conf.c:636 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:0:1359658283:1
            pin_mta_convert_cmdline_options_to_flist parameters flist

    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:23 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pcpst.c(78):406 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:2:0:1359658283:0
            connect to host=172.16.87.14, port=11962 OK
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:24 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta.c:2479 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:0:1359658283:0
            Config object search input flist
    0 PIN_FLD_POID           POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /search/pin -1 0
    0 PIN_FLD_FLAGS           INT [0] 0
    0 PIN_FLD_TEMPLATE        STR [0] "select X from /config/mta where F1 = V1 "
    0 PIN_FLD_ARGS          ARRAY [1] allocated 20, used 1
    1     PIN_FLD_CONFIG_MTA    ARRAY [0] allocated 20, used 1
    2         PIN_FLD_NAME            STR [0] "pin_deferred_act"
    0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS       ARRAY [0] allocated 20, used 1
    1     PIN_FLD_POID           POID [0] NULL poid pointer
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:24 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta.c:2484 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:3:7:1359658284:2
            Config object search output flist
    0 PIN_FLD_POID           POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /search/pin -1 0
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:24 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta.c:3138 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:7:1359658284:2
```

So the threads update the logs, like **pin_deferred_act:10233:1:7** --> where 1 specifies the log from the first thread, in the logfile.

I want to create log file for each thread, where the start point should be:

```
1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:
```

and end- point should be:

```
D Fri Feb 01 00:21:24 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in
```

(where date/timestamp will keep on modifying).
All the instances should go in one file.

For e.g.:

```
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:23 2013  <no machine>  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta_conf.c:636 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:0:1359658283:1
            pin_mta_convert_cmdline_options_to_flist parameters flist
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:23 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pcpst.c(78):406 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:2:0:1359658283:0
            connect to host=172.16.87.14, port=11962 OK
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:24 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta.c:2479 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:0:1359658283:0
            Config object search input flist
    0 PIN_FLD_POID           POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /search/pin -1 0
    0 PIN_FLD_FLAGS           INT [0] 0
    0 PIN_FLD_TEMPLATE        STR [0] "select X from /config/mta where F1 = V1 "
    0 PIN_FLD_ARGS          ARRAY [1] allocated 20, used 1
    1     PIN_FLD_CONFIG_MTA    ARRAY [0] allocated 20, used 1
    2         PIN_FLD_NAME            STR [0] "pin_deferred_act"
    0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS       ARRAY [0] allocated 20, used 1
    1     PIN_FLD_POID           POID [0] NULL poid pointer
    D Fri Feb 01 00:21:24 2013  App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in  pin_deferred_act:10233  pin_mta.c:3138 1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:7:1359658284:2
```

should go to one file - *Thread1.log*, and similarly for other threads, the file should be created as *Threadn.log* with the respectively.

Comment: What problem are you having?  Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @Dan, I tried the following:

>awk '/1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:/{i++}{print > "Thread"i}' logfile

This created separate file each time it encountered "1:App-BRM-Prod-Pri.acttv.in:pin_deferred_act:10233:1:", whereas I want that to be concatenated to one file for each thread.

Also, I tried csplit but couldn't get much out of it. I tried a few regular expression but I'm able to fetch only the following lines after first pattern match but not able fetch it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Files are a messy, non-scalable way of handling logs to begin with.  A better approach is to handle logs as streams of log entry messages connected source(s) -> sink(s).  Consider syslog, logplex or similar if Oracle provides alternative means of data collection.  Custom re-implementation might be feasible depending on logging IOPS bottlenecks or other factors.

Use of high resolution monotonic clocks and/or globally-ordered GUID timestamps are highly recommended. With wall time, be sure to use non-backwards compensated UTC everywhere synced to low strata time sources.

Above recommendations may vary according to needs of the application of course, so experiment and implement wisely.

Comment: Thanks Barry but the issue is that I do not have the access to the source code to modify the log messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think Barry's advice is useful, but in the event that you can't alter the application's log output, here is a quick Perl solution:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %logs;
my $last_log;
while (<$main_log_file>)  #open that application's log in this variable.
{
    if (/pin_deferred_act:\d+:(\d+):\d/)
    {
        unless (defined $logs{$1})
        {
            open $fh,'>',"Thread$1.log") or die "Can't open Thread $1 log: $!";
            $logs{$1} = $fh;
        }

        $last_log = $logs{$1}; 
    }

    if (defined $last_log)
    {
        print {$last_log} $_;
    }
    else
    {
        #Didn't find starting line.  Error handling?    
    }
}
```

This solution maintains a hash of open file handles to the log files for all threads.  I prefer this as it is more efficient if the input will have a lot of switching back and forth between the same threads.  It would break, however, if the application has more threads than you are allowed to have files open on your system.